# Error 'Gas price lower than required' meaning

Tags: gas, price

I'm noob in crypto and especially in ETH. I tried to pay with Metamask and received `Fail with error 'Gas price lower than required'`

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x72d06355423c09c2e0480ef9fd8efb778def6c1a5e83de3c3ea31ee97fb2daa7

Please could you explain what is mean? How do I fix it? And if it's impossible can I return my coins back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gas price is **the computational cost** needed to perform a specific transaction.

This error occurred due to **an **insufficient amount of gas limit**** provided. Consider reinitiate the gas the transaction with an **appropriate gas limit**.

[image]

The value of your transaction didn't leave your wallet, but a gas fee was already deducted due to the computations incurred.

You can read more about your error [here](https://info.etherscan.com/reason-for-failed-transaction/).